# Move MKAnnotation MKAnnotationView without removing

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to put a pin on top of the blue user location. But apparently, the MKAnnotation/view does not move when I change the coordinate property of the object.

Someone has achieved this without removing and adding the annotations again?

Comment: Did you considered to just set a different image for the  MKUserLocation annotation?

Comment: No because I want my image on top of the standard one.

Comment: Maybe your designer can create the default one with a pin on top? ;)

Comment: The standard one has some animations to it ;)